# Can't require swagger-jsdoc

Tags: swagger, swagger-jsdocs

When I run the code it showing **Must use import to load ES Module:** error message. How can I solve this..?

error code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

Comment: any one help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Now I resolved the issue by downgrading swagger-jsdoc to 6.0.1